# In Memory Cache

Tags: memcached, appfabric

I was looking at MS's Velocity back in 2009 as an in-memory caching solution. Now since that point it has been rolled up in the AppFabric solution which does a host of things including caching. I have "Road tested" MemCached a a while back as well and found it a little unstable.

My question is: We are only looking for a caching solution and just was wondering which was faster to get up and running, is one more reliable then the other? Are there any other options out there?

Comment: Where did you get your windows memcached distribution?  There have been a few at various levels of support/completion.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow uses [Redis](http://redis.io/) according to [this article on High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html)

We've been using AppFabric on Woot.com for a while now and have found it pretty stable.

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing I've seen regarding the reliability of memcached on Windows is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011441/caching-solutions/3185827#3185827) from last year.

I've nothing really to compare AppFabric against so take this with a pinch of salt, but I found it pretty quick to get up and running - from the install to having some code running is under an hour. The TDD story isn't so good at the moment, there's a set of hoops to jump through - see [Ron Jacobs blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/05/03/using-moq-with-windows-server-appfabric-caching.aspx) for details.

> Are there any other options out there?

Sure.

- [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)
- [SharedCache](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/)
- [Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html)